# Compact notation for functions in Map containers?

Tags: function, scala, collections

I'm building a map of enumeration entries to simple data accessors in an object. Here's an example (from the interpretor) using Int as the key:

```
class Obj(a: Int, b: Int) {
    def getA = a
    def getB = b
}

val m : Map[Int, (Obj) => Int] = Map(
    (2, (o: Obj) => o.getA)
);

val d = m(2)(new Obj(3,4))
```

This works fine, but having to write a function with the :Obj type explicitally in the parameter in each map value seems unnecessary:

```
(o: Obj) => o.getA
```

Is there a tighter syntax I'm missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this case the type will be inferred, for instance:

```
scala> val m : Map[Int, (Obj) => Int] = Map(
     |     (2, _.getA)
     | )
m: Map[Int,Obj => Int] = Map(2 -> <function1>)

scala> m(2)( new Obj(3,4) )
res0: Int = 3
```

Here I used the underscore to make the function definition as terse as possible, but you could also define the function as: `o => o.getA`. It can be useful if the argument is used more than once, for instance: `o => o.getA + o.getB`.

Comment: Thanks. I'll use this and put in a comment so the next Java programming coming along can also understand it :)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get rid of the type annotation on the left hand side (not always a good idea, but good for conciseness) you can, keeping your original right hand side, or slightly shorter:

```
val m = Map( (2, (_: Obj).getA) )
```

As an aside, in Scala it would be more idiomatic to define your class as

```
class Obj(val a: Int, val b: Int)
// or
case class Obj(a: Int, b: Int)
```

and refer to your fields as simply `a` and `b`, since the compiler provides you with getters.